# Eloquent way to perform text search text on given ids only

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table with two columns that contain some text data.
What i want to do is to search these columns but only for the given ids.
So far the i am getting the result for the whole db disregarding the ids supplied. This is because orwhere condition is set up wrong. 
I cannot figure out how to set up properly

```
   $qu = \App\AppModels\Quotation::with([
        'products.product',
        'paymentTerms',
        'deliveryTerms',
        'company',
        'status',
        'createdByUser'
    ]);


    if($search_q){
        $qu->where( 'name', '=', $search_q )
        ->orWhere( 'reference', '=', $search_q )
        ->orWhere( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q )
        ->orWhere( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q . '%' )
        ->orWhere( 'name', 'LIKE', $search_q . '%' )
        ->orWhere( 'reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q )
        ->orWhere( 'reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q . '%' )
        ->orWhere( 'reference', 'LIKE', $search_q . '%' );
    }

    $quotations = $qu->where('created_at', '>=', $records_from)
    ->whereIn('id',array_unique($quotation_ids))
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Are you getting the correct results when you don't provide a `$search_q` value?

Comment: yes the results are correct, its just the wherein gets mixed in the or condition, so the id gets ignored

Answer (score 2):

You can use "parameter grouping" to group your `orWhere` queries. So you could do:

```
    if($search_q){
    $qu = $qu->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where( 'name', '=', $search_q )
        ->orWhere( 'reference', '=', $search_q )
        ->orWhere( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q )
        ->orWhere( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q . '%' )
        ->orWhere( 'name', 'LIKE', $search_q . '%' )
        ->orWhere( 'reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q )
        ->orWhere( 'reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q . '%' )
        ->orWhere( 'reference', 'LIKE', $search_q . '%' );
    });
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is the way to do it. i found the solution. But thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0):

After some more research i figured out the answer.

```
  $qu = \App\AppModels\Quotation::with([
        'products.product',
        'paymentTerms',
        'deliveryTerms',
        'company',
        'status',
        'createdByUser'
    ])
    ->whereIn('id',array_unique($quotation_ids));


    if($search_q){

        $qu->where(function ($query) use($search_q) {
            $query->orWhere( 'name', '=', $search_q )
                ->orWhere( 'reference', '=', $search_q )
                ->orWhere( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q )
                ->orWhere( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q . '%' )
                ->orWhere( 'name', 'LIKE', $search_q . '%' )
                ->orWhere( 'reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q )
                ->orWhere( 'reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_q . '%' )
                ->orWhere( 'reference', 'LIKE', $search_q . '%' );
        });
    }

    $quotations = $qu->where('created_at', '>=', $records_from)
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->get();
```